# Correct that of usage

Tags: word-usage

“The first known cuisine of Peru was *that of* the Incas, who used natural resources of their far expanded empire”
Is this correct?

Comment: This needs to include the source (and should include the rest of the question too). You should also explain your thoughts: why do you think this is (or isn't) correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed correct. Here, *that* is used as a pronoun. Here are some equivalent formulations:

> The first known cuisine of Peru was that of the Incas 
> The first known cuisine of Peru was [the cuisine] of the Incas

*that of* is used here because it would confusing at best and ungrammatical at worst to say

> The first known cuisine of Peru was the Inca's.

Is the first known cuisine of Peru the first known cuisine of the Inca's, or is the first known cuisine of Peru the cuisine of the Inca's? "That of" makes it clear that "first known" refers to "Peru" and not "Incas."